# Getting the entire path where a .mdb file is present by providing the database(.mdb) name in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get the entire path where a .mdb file is present by providing the database(.mdb) name in excel-vba.

When I install an application in my system, a database (.mdb file) will be created in the installation path. I want to take some data from that database(.mdb file) and use it in an excel file.

This would path would be different in different systems. I want my excel-vba code to automatically look for the database (.mdb file) and take the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveWorkbook.Path` is where the current excel worksheet is found. assuming your database name does not change, then using this value `& "MyDatabase.mdb"` should find your database

Comment: Agree with you, but if OP is installing an addin then `ThisWorkbook.Path` would be more appropriate, since an addin would never be the active workbook.

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest a different approach, as I understand the question in a the way, that it is necessary to find the *.mdb* file first - there is only the name provided.

In that case, you will find help in the following article - including some working code ;)

[Microsoft KB185476](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185476/en-us)

And for the part with the full-path:

```
Sub ShowFileAccessInfo(filespec)
    Dim fs, d, f, s
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(filespec)
    s = UCase(f.Path) & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Created: " & f.DateCreated & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Last Accessed: " & f.DateLastAccessed & vbCrLf
    s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
    MsgBox s, 0, "File Access Info"
End Sub
```

*from excel-help (file-object)